# Transforming attribute values based on a dictionary encoded as a tree variable

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

It should be apparent what I'm trying to achieve looking at these sample files:

Input:

```
<root>
    <node type="A"/>
    <node type="B"/>
</root>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="fixes">
        <fix from="A" to="AA"/>
        <fix from="B" to="BB"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@type[string()=$fixes/fix/@from]">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
                <xsl:value-of select="$fixes/fix[@from=self::node()]/@to"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output:

```
<root>
    <node type="AA"/>
    <node type="BB"/>
</root>
```

Actual output (using saxon9he):

```
<root>
    <node type=""/>
    <node type=""/>
</root>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `self::node()` with `current()` to select the `@type` attribute matched on (and not the context node of the predicate, which is a `fix` element).

In general for such tasks I would suggest to define a key

```
<xsl:key name="fix" match="fix" use="@from"/>
```

and then rewrite

as

```
<xsl:template match="@type[key('fix', ., $fixes)]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="key('fix', ., $fixes)/@to"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll look into the key mechanism also.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the current value by taking in a variable:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="fixes">
        <fix from="A" to="AA"/>
        <fix from="B" to="BB"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@type[.= $fixes/fix/@from]">
        <xsl:variable name="current" select="."/>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="$fixes/fix[@from = $current]/@to"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, that also works, but using `current()` as suggested by Martin above is less verbose and just as effective.  I upvoted your answer though.